# Insert blank page before TOC

Tags: blank-page

I have been trying to put a blank page before the table of contents, but Latex seems to ignore `\newpage` or `\doubleclearpage`. The only thing that worked was `\afterpage{\null\newpage}` of the package afterpage, with a problem though: it inserted two white pages instead of one.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,includefoot,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=27mm,tmargin=25mm, bmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=2pt plus1pt, indent=15pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges]{babel}
\addto\captionsportuges{% Replace "english" with the language you use
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Índice}%
}
\addto\captionsportuges{\renewcommand{\partname}{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{XCharter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % page number on bottom right
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% supress horizontal line
\pagestyle{fancy} % activate the style fancy
\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000
\newenvironment{dedication}
{
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
    \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
        \raggedleft
    }%
    {
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
    \clearpage
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        
        
        
        \newcommand\nbvspace[1][3]{\vspace*{\stretch{#1}}}
        
        \newcommand\nbstretchyspace{\spaceskip0.5em plus 0.25em minus 0.25em}
        
        \newcommand{\nbtitlestretch}{\spaceskip0.6em}
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{center}
            \bfseries
            \nbvspace[1]
            \Huge
            {\nbtitlestretch\LARGE
                Something of no importance}
            
            \nbvspace[1]
            \normalsize
            
            THE BOOK
            
            \nbvspace[1]
            \small Foreword by \\[0.5em]
            \Large A. Author \\[0.8em]
            
            
            PLACE\\
            \large
            PRINTER
            \nbvspace[1]
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{10cm}
        \textbf{Authors}
        
        
        A Author
        
        B Author
        \vspace{25mm}
        
        \textbf{Edition}
        Press of Somwhere
        
        ISBN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        
        \copyright Printed at home
        
    \end{minipage}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    
    
    
    
    
    
    \begin{dedication}
        In memory of somebody \\
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        C. D.   
        
        \vspace{8mm}
        The the unknown reader \\
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        A. B.
    \end{dedication}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    %\clearpage
    
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \tableofcontents
    \setcounter{page}{3}
    \newpage
    \part{Part one}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \chapter{Third chapter}
    
    \part{Part two}
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \chapter{Third chapter}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is probably and even page/odd page issue.  The TOC is supposed to be on an odd page, which it apparently already is.  So a single blank page would put it on an even page, in which case it will move to the next odd page.

Comment: The easy solution would be to use [oneside] with book and manually add blank pages where you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `\cleardoublepage` and `\thispagestyle{empty}` this will ensure that a new right-hand page is started and that this page is blank without any headers or footers.

For the table of contents to start at a specific page number, you should reset the page counter right after the blank page.

```
\documentclass{book}
% ... [your other package and settings] ...

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        % Title page content
    \end{titlepage}
    
    % Other front matter content like dedication
    \begin{dedication}
        % Dedication content
    \end{dedication}

    % Insert a blank page
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \null
    \newpage

    % Start the page numbering
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{3}

    % Table of contents
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage


    \part{Part one}
    % ... rest of your document ...
\end{document}
```